# R case-insensitive %in%

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to create a case-insensitive `%in%` like function. I have so far created this:

```
qs <- function(str, vec, na.rm = TRUE) {
  stopifnot("str must have length 1" = length(str) == 1)
  if(na.rm) {
    any(stringi::stri_detect_fixed(str, na.omit(vec), max_count = 1, opts_fixed = list(case_insensitive = TRUE)))
  } else {
    any(stringi::stri_detect_fixed(str, vec, max_count = 1, opts_fixed = list(case_insensitive = TRUE)))
  }
```

For my use case, I need this vectorized, so I can do:

```
vecqs <- Vectorize(qs, "str")
```

However, I have read that `Vectorize` is rather slow. I have also been reading about `data.table::chmatch` and the `fastmatch` package. Both of these implement their own `%in%` type function (`chmatch` for `data.table`). These would be great but I don't know how to make `chmatch` case insensitive.

Comment: you could simply use `tolower(X) %in% tolower(Y)` which would be case-insensitive as everything is converted to lowercase. Only mild improvements would be obtained by using a `Rcpp` function using a ASCI or UTF-8 lookup table matching strings iteratively (if any at all).

Comment: with data.table the option could be to make a dummy column `dat[,to_match:=toupper(target][,to_match%chin%list_of_matches]` then drop the dummy column (or just combine)

Comment: No reason for assigning the dummy column. Simply use `tolower` or `toupper` on each argument in the comparison of `%chin%`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments above, I came to the relatively simple solution below:

```
#' Quick Search
#'
#' Quick case-insensitive search of strings in a character vector
#'
#' @param str a character vector: the values to be matched
#' @param vec a character vector: the values to be matched against
#'
#' @details Utilizes \code{data.table::`%chin%`} to rapidly complete a case-insensitive search
#' through a character vector to return a logical vector of string detections.
#' Will always return TRUE or FALSE for each position of \code{str} regardless of NA missing values 
#' in either provided vector. NA in \code{str} will never match an NA value in \code{vec}.
#'
#' @return a logical vector of length \code{length(str)}
#'
#' @export
#' @importFrom data.table %chin%
#'
#' @examples
#' x <- c("apple","banana","cherry",NA)
#' "apple" %qsin% x
#' c("APPLE","BANANA","coconut", NA) %qsin% x
#'
`%qsin%` <- function(str, vec) {
  tolower(str) %chin% na.omit(tolower(vec))
}
```

Comment: might want to add an explicit `if (!require("data.table")) ...` unless this is being used in a context where `data.table` will definitely be loaded.  (I missed the `data.table::` in the docs the first time through)